# conda install pkg with wrong python version

Tags: anaconda

I have a conda-env, in which python --version 3.7;
when I use conda install to install some python pkgs, It always installs pkgs-py36 and updates/downgrades existing-pkgs-py37 to pkgs-py36.
Another conda-env with python=2.7 has the similar problem.

conda --version 4.5.11; and other computers work well with this conda version.

Comment: what happens if you do `conda install python=3.7 <some-packages>`? Usually downgrading python hints towards conda having problems satisfying certain dependencies.

Comment: this seems to work well. And this problem may be not caused by anaconda, but pytorch. many thanks.